# MiTM attacks SSL to SSL

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle

I was wondering what ways there are to MiTM a client link to the server where I would give them a public key that they would then send their data via https://example.com using my key.

Then without their knowledge I decode it on my machine, reencode with the real keys that my machine got from the server and pass it on creating an SSL proxy/MiTM ... I have Googled these terms constantly but only find sslstrip which is not what I need - there has to be an SSL connection.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using something like [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/). I hope this helps you get started.

Hopefully someone else will chime in with more alternatives, as this is the only one I am familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of information about [SSL Renegotiation](http://www.educatedguesswork.org/2009/11/understanding_the_tls_renegoti.html) attacks.  This is not quite what you asked though, at least I don't think this is what you asked.  Can you adjust the flow of your question, as I think you have a couple of optional predicates there.

Comment: This is pretty much what I want accept I was thinking about it a bit different in psuedo code... 

client(encode)>>>>hacker(decode)>>>hacker(encode)>>>server(decode).... so there are 2 keys envolved here...but what you sent me should be fine for my tests, thanks I will have a look though any ideas on the other one then give me a shout.

Answer (score 1):

Having the victim's traffic routed through your machine, the only way for the attack you're planning to work is to get the target to trust your public key. To do that, you either need to install your public key into their Trusted Root Certificates or to get them to ignore the browser's warning. This can be done using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).

**So, to recap:**

1. Get the traffic through your machine.
2. Get the target to trust your public key.
3. Decrypt the traffic using your private key.

Comment: yes :) and then forward it on to the true destination is the final part